# Java out of memory using PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, memory

There is another possibly related question on this but it didn't have answers and the asker didn't clarify any.

So when I'm going over a large result set in postgres, java seems to break.

The query I'm running is trying to get around 5.5M rows. Basically I'm trying to populate a Neo4J database from a Postgres db.

I won't bother posting the code unless someone asks as it's pretty generic I think. Here is the exception output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater$AtomicReferenceFieldUpdaterImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.newUpdater(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.SQLException.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1818)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:374)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:254)
    at sqlToGraph.SqlToGraph.main(SqlToGraph.java:52)
```

Line 52 is just the query, as so:

```
rs = st.executeQuery("select player_lo, player_hi, total_hands_lo, total_hands_hi, (pc_lo + pc_hi)/2 as avg_pc from pair");
```

So I guess rs is getting pretty big. I suppose I could just use LIMIT and OFFSET and run the program a few hundred times or have it reset rs in a loop or so, but I'd rather not have to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Set the fetch size to something reasonable (`st.setFetchSize(rowCount)`).  You can experiment with this.
2. Put everything in a transaction with autocommit off (`con.setAutoCommit(false)`).

See [this explanation](http://abhirama.wordpress.com/2009/01/07/postgresql-jdbc-and-large-result-sets/) and [the documentation](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor).

Comment: Thanks, that totally fixed it. Until Neo4J made it run out of memory. Oh well, more questions to ask...